# Transparent bitmaps or graphics in gui objects initially appear wrong

Tags: graphics, bugs, front-end, image, opacity

**Bug introduced in V9.0 or earlier and persisting through V11.3**

---

I have a problem with images with alpha channel which I want to use as labels on `Button` etc. Unless I scroll or move cursor over the `Button` the alpha channel is considered a white background.

```
Button[
 SetAlphaChannel[Graphics@Rectangle[], Graphics@Disk[]],
 Print[1]]
```

[image]

Same with a `Graphics` in various objects, shown here with the ReverseColor stylesheet:

```
icon = Graphics[{Green, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> {15, 15}, Background -> None];
{Button[Dynamic@Row@{icon}, {}],
 Panel[Dynamic@Row@{icon}],
 Pane[Dynamic@Row@{icon}, BaseStyle -> {Background -> White}],
 Framed[Dynamic@Row@{icon}, Background -> White]}
```

[image]

For more examples, see [Dynamic graphics appears first with wrong background](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/121082/89).

How to force the first appearance to be there instantaneously, without moving the mouse over. I'm working on Win7 V10.1. Is there any stable solution to this problem?

---

**Edit 10.09.15**

I reported the issue and received a bug confirmation:

> [...] Unfortunately, we do not have a work-around for this issue and I apologize for any inconvenience this is causing you. 
>   I have forwarded an incident report to our developers with the information you provided. [...]

Comment: yep, I would say its a front end bug...perhaps a workaround can be found by fiddling with styesheets

Comment: Interesting, on 10.1 on Win8.1 I don't need to scroll over to change the appearance, but there *is* a pause before it changes on its own

Comment: You should set `CacheGraphics->False`. i.e. `Button[Style[SetAlphaChannel[Graphics@Rectangle[], Graphics@Disk[]], 
  CacheGraphics -> False], Print[1]]`

Comment: This issue has wider affects; see also: [(121082)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/121082/121)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The workaround given in comments works.

> You should set `CacheGraphics->False`. i.e.
>
> ```
> Button[ 
>   Style[ 
>     SetAlphaChannel[ Graphics@Rectangle[], Graphics@Disk[]], 
>     CacheGraphics -> False
>   ], 
>   Print[1]
> ]
> ```
>
> – ihojnicki Jul 13 at 19:59

One can put it in `BaseStyle -> {CacheGraphics -> False}` too.