# Dynamic graphics appears first with wrong background

Tags: graphics, dynamic

This is one of those annoying things that you put aside for years before making a post of it. Put a dynamic `Graphics` into a gui object (`Button`, `Panel`, etc.), and the result will show the graphics with the stylesheet default background until the mouse is moved over the object. In my example, I've used the **ReverseColor** stylesheet (**Format** > **Stylesheet** > **ReverseColor**) as it demonstrates my problem more clearly, but it happens with the default stylesheet's white background the same way.

**Example 1**

If the graphics is wrapped in `Dynamic` it appears with the stylesheet background. Note, that `Button` is even worse, as the label need not be dynamic to be malformed.

```
icon = Graphics[{Green, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> {15, 15}, Background -> None];

{Button[Row@{icon}, {}],
 Panel[Row@{icon}],
 Pane[Row@{icon}, BaseStyle -> {Background -> White}],
 Framed[Row@{icon}, Background -> White]}

{Button[Dynamic@Row@{icon}, {}],
 Panel[Dynamic@Row@{icon}],
 Pane[Dynamic@Row@{icon}, BaseStyle -> {Background -> White}],
 Framed[Dynamic@Row@{icon}, Background -> White]}
```

[image]

Note, that you don't have to click on anything, just move the mouse over the output. Clearly, as the output is in a list, it is enough to update one of them.

**Example 2**

Any function that wraps the dynamic graphics and appears on screen (i.e. is not `Identity`, `HoldForm` or similar) results in bad behaviour.

```
{
 Panel[Dynamic@icon],
 Panel[Dynamic@{icon}],
 Panel[Dynamic@Row@{icon}],
 Panel[Dynamic@Column@{icon}],
 Panel[Dynamic@Grid@{{icon}}]
 }
```

[image]

**Example 3**

I assume, that `Button` internally puts a `Dynamic` around its first argument, as it appears with the black background even if there is no `Dynamic` around the graphics. Furthermore, if a `FinishDynamic[]` is issued right after (has to appear on screen, hence the `List` wrapper), one can clearly see that the `Button` appears first malformed after which it turns ok.

```
Button[icon]
Pause[.5];
List@FinishDynamic[]
```

[image]

**Q1:** Why `Background -> None` uses the stylesheet background instead of inheriting the background of the wrapping gui object? It seems like, that `Graphics` inherits the background for from the immediately wrapping function (for one level), and if it has no `Background` specification, it reverts to the stylesheet's.

**Q2:** Why is this behaviour corrected when mouse moves over the object?

**Q3:** Why is there a `Dynamic` internally around the first argument of `Button`?

Is it a graphics-card related glitch? Can we consider it a bug?

Comment: Can anyone reproduce it? I'm on _Mathematica_ 10.4.0.0, Win7 64.

Comment: This appears to be the same issue as [Transparent bitmaps in controllers. Problem with initial appearance](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85521/5478) and `CacheGraphics -> False` fix given by ihojnicki works here too.

Comment: @Kuba adding `BaseStyle -> {CacheGraphics -> False}` to `icon` fixes all examples given, so I am marking this as a duplicate.  István, if you find a case where this fix *does not* work please update your question and let me know, and I shall reopen it.

Comment: By the way the problem exists in 10.1.0 under Windows, but not in 7.0.1.

Comment: @Wizard, Kuba I'm fine with the close, but there was a reason I didn't find Kuba's post. It is not a bitmap/texture specific issue.

Comment: Indeed, and I am glad you posted this.  In addition to the linking already provided by \[duplicate\] I shall add a Related: link to the other Q&A to increase the visibility of this one.