# Dynamic's SynchronousUpdating->False broken in Graphics

Tags: graphics, bugs, front-end, dynamic

**Bug reproduced in V10.4.1 and persisting through V11.2**

> A support case with the identification [CASE:3699190] was created.

> [...] It does appear that `SynchronousUpdating -> False` is not interacting with `CacheGraphics` properly. I have forwarded an incident report to our developers with the information you provided. [...]

---

When `Dynamic` content is bigger, the updating is broken:

```
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10^4, 2}];
show = False;

Checkbox[Dynamic@show]

Dynamic[
   If[  TrueQ@show, Length[data], "not shown"], 
   SynchronousUpdating -> False
]

Graphics[{
  Dynamic[
    If[TrueQ@show, Line[data], {}], 
    SynchronousUpdating -> False
  ]}, 
  PlotRange -> 1, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

As we can see `Length` is updated correctly while the plot remains populated and only flashes during next switch.

It won't happen if `data` is smaller, e.g `10^2`.

Comment: I just have checked on Windows 7 x64 with *Mathematica* 11.2.0 and can't reproduce the bug with `data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10^4, 2}];`, but with version 8.0.4 on the same machine it is present. It indeed appears when with version 11.2.0 I set `data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10^5, 2}];`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov yes, `10^4` does not always show this for me either, I guess it is related to FE memory consumption etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems to be another "feature" related to `CacheGraphics`, this will work correctly:

```
Graphics[{
   Dynamic[
     If[TrueQ @ show, Line[data], {}], 
     SynchronousUpdating -> False
   ]}, 
   PlotRange -> 1, 
   Frame -> True, 
   BaseStyle -> CacheGraphics -> False
]
```

[image]

Another because we already know that: [Transparent bitmaps or graphics in gui objects initially appear wrong](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85521/5478)