# Unexpected styling of a Button when used as PlotLabel

Tags: graphics, bugs, front-end, button

**Bug introduced in 8 or earlier and fixed in 11.3**

<sub>Reported to the support as [CASE:3984748]</sub>

---

Consider the following plot with a `Button` placed as `PlotLabel`:

```
ListLinePlot[Table[RandomReal[1, 1000], {i, 8}], PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLabel -> Button["Press me!", Appearance -> None]]
```

[image: screenshot]

After clicking the button and moving the mouse out it gets blue background:

[image: screenshot2]

(Note that this doesn't happen if the number of plotted points is substantially reduced: e.g., replace `1000` with `100` in the code above and you won't see this.)

**How can I avoid this?** I wish to have the default appearance after releasing the button.

(*Mathematica* 11.2.0, Windows 7 x64.)

Comment: same issue in version  9.0  MS Windows (64-bit)

Comment: Does basestyle/cachegraphics/false for plot help? - sent from Nokia 3310

Comment: @Kuba Yes, `BaseStyle -> {"CacheGraphics" -> False}` solved the problem. You can post the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov ok, done, please report it anyway.

Comment: @Kuba Reported to the support as [CASE:3984748]: "<...> I was able to reproduce the behavior you described and will forward this to our development team. <...>"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix is to add `BaseStyle -> CacheGraphics -> False` around:

```
ListLinePlot[
  Table[RandomReal[1, 1000], {i, 8}]
, PlotRange -> All
, PlotLabel -> Button["Press me!", Appearance -> None]
, BaseStyle -> CacheGraphics -> False
]
```

I would love to elaborate but this option is undocumented and the reason I knew it may be related is because I have faced similar issues:

- [Transparent bitmaps or graphics in gui objects initially appear wrong](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85521/5478)
- [Dynamic's SynchronousUpdating->False broken in Graphics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125119/5478)